# How do I move application windows between desktops?

Tags: macos

If I have an application open in desktop 1, what's the simplest way to move it over to desktop 2? In snow leopard I could do this by dragging the window to the edge of the screen. After leaving it there for a second or so it would move to an adjacent desktop. This doesn't seem to work in Lion.

Does anyone know how to move windows between desktops in Lion?

Comment: Dragging the window to the edge of the screen works for me in Lion. Just remember that Lion does not wrap desktops, so if you drag a window in the first desktop to the left edge, nothing happens, but if you drag it to the right edge, then the window moves to the second desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go into Mission Control (formerly known as Expose in Snow Leopard), then drag the window from your current desktop the thumbnail of the other desktop, which will be at the top of the screen.

[image]

Comment: You can only move windows from the current desktop to another, not across desktop as Expose allowed.

Comment: And, weirdly enough, if you have two screens, you can not drag a window to the other screen than the one it is on, even though they're shown separately in Mission Control.